# Clicking a button with selenium using Xpath doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am currently new to Selenium and webscraping.
I would like to click on button on a page.
However, my program cannot find it using this Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[3]/header/div[1]/div/nav[1]/ul/li[8]/a
```

The HTML code:
[HTML screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAgMm.png)

Is there something wrong with my Xpath?
Can you please help me with that?

Thank you

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
  link= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Twoje konto: trader122")))
```

**Notes:** Add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```