# How to enter text into a website via selenium and xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using selenium to try and input text into a text field on a webpage via its xpath. My code to do this is as follows:

```
import names
from fake_email import Email
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


#initialize_VPN(save=1,area_input=['united kingdom'])
url = "https://freesim.vodafone.co.uk/check-out-payasyougo-campaign?kw=2076373398_78217941804_388970929371_aud-857274915513:kwd-319973502705_c___k_CjwKCAjwmbqoBhAgEiwACIjzEJyXn61Hv89l8EceOUp8kVymNDekTIKzbdghus8v4g_3lYX7eaFMGBoCiqIQAvD_BwE_k_;expubdata=ken_clickid;cpdir=%7bunescapedlpurl%7d&cid=ppc-UK_19_AO_P_X_J_I_D_PAYG_BAU_Promo_Text-Brand_Google_Free-SIM_NA_NA_Free-SIM_Mix_Mix_NA_Exact__2076373398&kpid=go_cmp-2076373398_adg-78217941804_ad-388970929371_aud-857274915513:kwd-319973502705_dev-c_ext-_prd-&vfadid=2076373398&cid=ppc&gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwmbqoBhAgEiwACIjzEJyXn61Hv89l8EceOUp8kVymNDekTIKzbdghus8v4g_3lYX7eaFMGBoCiqIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds"

driver = uc.Chrome()


fname = names.get_first_name()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
button = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
button.click()
time.sleep(10)
fname_field = driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="txtFirstName"]')
fname_field.send_keys(fname)
```

I am 99% sure the xpath is correct since I inspected the element and used the copy xpath function. I am really not sure where the error could be, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more information so that we can execute the code and help you?

Comment: Is that the `id` or is that the `name`?

Comment: [Don't sleep Selenium, make it wait for elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-waits). Also, why use xpath when working with web pages? You have an `id`, just [query for that](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#first-matching-element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input field is located on an `iframe`, so Selenium cannot find it. First you need to put focus on the [frame](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/), then find the desired field.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = r'https://freesim.vodafone.co.uk/check-out-payasyougo-campaign?kw=2076373398_78217941804_388970929371_aud-857274915513:kwd-319973502705_c___k_CjwKCAjwmbqoBhAgEiwACIjzEJyXn61Hv89l8EceOUp8kVymNDekTIKzbdghus8v4g_3lYX7eaFMGBoCiqIQAvD_BwE_k_;expubdata=ken_clickid;cpdir=%7bunescapedlpurl%7d&cid=ppc-UK_19_AO_P_X_J_I_D_PAYG_BAU_Promo_Text-Brand_Google_Free-SIM_NA_NA_Free-SIM_Mix_Mix_NA_Exact__2076373398&kpid=go_cmp-2076373398_adg-78217941804_ad-388970929371_aud-857274915513:kwd-319973502705_dev-c_ext-_prd-&vfadid=2076373398&cid=ppc&gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwmbqoBhAgEiwACIjzEJyXn61Hv89l8EceOUp8kVymNDekTIKzbdghus8v4g_3lYX7eaFMGBoCiqIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)


button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
print(button)
button.click()

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID,"iframe-content")
print(iframe)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

fname_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtFirstName")
print(fname_field)

driver.quit()

--------------------------

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7aefcbe01219c4bbce304c718460b2d7", element="18C5442A47779529F843070D61BEC870_element_9")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7aefcbe01219c4bbce304c718460b2d7", element="18C5442A47779529F843070D61BEC870_element_10")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7aefcbe01219c4bbce304c718460b2d7", element="5D442C80758D462E606746AEB6E5314B_element_45")>
```

Answer (score 0):

Targeting them using a CSS Selector would be effective.

Moreover, it could be the case that either the element is not located or not interactable,
so, you can add the following lines to your code without any additional imports:

```
delay=3 # set a delay time which you can adjust accordingly
selector="input#txtFirstName" 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
elem.send_keys("John Doe")
```

If that still fails for you, you can do it using javascript:

```
name = "John Doe"
selector="input#txtFirstName"
driver.execute_script(f'document.querySelector("{selector}").value = "{name}";')
```

Answer (score -1):

As Mike suggested instead of `time.sleep()` you can use `WebDriverWait`. In my automation code I have used Page-object-model (POM) pattern in my python selenium project to avoid these kind of issues. a very good example for  [using POM pattern](https://github.com/gunesmes/page-object-python-selenium) also see [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595200/15328031)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


// to wait for 10 seconds
fname_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtFirstName"]'))
)
```